# How work with NestedVariant object in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have loaded a dataset from `tfds` where the data is in a `NestedVariant` object. How do I extract the values from there?

E.g.:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
ds = tfds.load("rlu_control_suite", split="train") 
for example in ds.take(1):
     print(example["steps"])
```

Output:

```
<tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops._NestedVariant object at 0x2c3324940>
```

I can't find the docs on how to work with this object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tf.data.Dataset.flat_map` to convert a nested dataset of datasets into a single dataset:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

ds = tfds.load("rlu_control_suite", split="train") 
ds = ds.flat_map(lambda x: x['steps'])
for example in ds.take(1):
    print(example)
```

```
{
    'action': < tf.Tensor: shape = (1, ),
    dtype = float32,
    numpy = array([0.6250813], dtype = float32) > ,
    'discount': < tf.Tensor: shape = (),
    dtype = float32,
    numpy = 1.0 > ,
    'is_first': < tf.Tensor: shape = (),
    dtype = bool,
    numpy = True > ,
    'is_last': < tf.Tensor: shape = (),
    dtype = bool,
    numpy = False > ,
    'is_terminal': < tf.Tensor: shape = (),
    dtype = bool,
    numpy = False > ,
    'observation': {
        'position': < tf.Tensor: shape = (3, ),
        dtype = float32,
        numpy = array([-0.00654944, -0.99999475, 0.00324196], dtype = float32) > ,
        'velocity': < tf.Tensor: shape = (2, ),
        dtype = float32,
        numpy = array([-0.0186821, 0.00950337], dtype = float32) >
    },
    'reward': < tf.Tensor: shape = (),
    dtype = float32,
    numpy = 1.6778985e-06 >
}
```